# Are Magura HS33e levers compatible with HS22 brakes?

Tags: brakes, electric-power, magura, hydraulic

I plan to convert a bike with Magura HS22 hydraulic brakes to electric. Thus I would like to replace the brake lever by one having the controller output to stop the motor while braking.

From my research Magura propose only one such replacement part, the HS33E.

Did anyone try to use those lever on the HS22 braking system? Are they compatible?

Comment: Welcome to the website! While I do not know an answer to the question, I had technical issues with Magura components before, and writing to them via their website's support form was of some help. I suggest you try asking Magura directly, it is worth a try. Also, you can look though technical documentation available on their website, maybe an answer about component's compatibility can be found there. Good luck!